# Remove Lubuntu partition and keep Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning

Last night I installed Lubuntu 11.10 on my desktop PC. Before that I only had Ubuntu 11.10, but now I have a "Dual-Boot" PC, with GRUB. Now, I want to uninstall Lubuntu because it doesn't like to me.

I tried to do that on Lubuntu's Live-CD GParted, but it has partitions that I don't know. And I don't want to play with that, I don't want to lose my Ubuntu data, these are my partitions:

[image]

The 38 GB partition is Ubuntu.

What I need to do is delete Lubuntu and enter to Ubuntu directly on the boot. Also, remember the Swap's partition!

Comment: Protip: Avoid messing with your partions like that by doing `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`, Instead of creating partions at Random. sda6 and  I *guess* sda7 are Lubuntu's partitions, delete those.

Answer (score 1):

First Delete all the Extended (the Teal one), and ALL inside it. Then make a Primary Partition Formatted as Linux-Swap, of equal size to your RAM. Then expand the 38Gb Partition to all remain Free Space. This need to be done via LiveCD.

Answer (score 1):

I followed these instructions and was left with a grub rescue prompt when I tried to boot, and a message "partition not found". I had to reinstall grub from a live CD using these instructions: http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.ca/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html. I can't say for sure, but I suspect this happened because the partition I deleted contained the last Ubuntu I installed (the alpha for 12.04).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the partition of the OS u wanna delete ... using live cd and run in terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

if u dont know which partition is which mount it from nautilus and check ur home directory and see which files u may hav only on ubuntu and only on xubuntu and delete the appropriate partition..